# How to get all values from array by using lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a multidimensional array:

```lua
result = {
  {
    data = {
      language = "English",
      name = "Freak Out",
      list = {
        {
          type = "songs",
          album = "1234"
        }, {
          type = "songs",
          album = "4234"
        }, {
          type = "songs",
          album = "5829"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do I dynamically access the list in this array?

This code is printing first album (`1234`):

```lua
for i, v in pairs(result) do print(v.data.list[1].album) end
```

I want to print all `album`s with their `type`. How do I do this?

Comment: Is list actually an array, because in the format you specified its an object.  Objects cannot be formatted like that.

Answer (score 6):

`result` is a list of tables
`result[i].data.list` is a list of tables.

```
for _, res in ipairs(result) do
  for _, song in ipairs(res.data.list) do
    print(song.type, song.album)
  end
end
```

this outputs

```
songs   1234
songs   4234
songs   5829
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need know table have two type in lua.One is hash table, and another is array.In your code. *result*'s member and *result.data* is a hash table, every element have a string key.*result* and *result.data.list* is a array table, all the member in the table have the number key, the default index start by 1.

Second, to traverse the two type table, there are two functions, pairs for hash table and [iparis](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-ipairs) for array table.

print all album in the list(array):

```
for k, v in ipairs(res.data.list) do
    print(v.type, v.album)
end
```

Comment: Internal implementation using hashing aside, all tables in Lua are dictionaries—there is only one type. A key can be any type and value except `nil` and NaN. Some of the keys in a table can be positive integers. Some such tables have a [sequence](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.7). A table with a sequence can have any additional keys. As keys are added or removed, a table can change between having a sequence and not having a sequence. There is still only one type.

Comment: Thanks first.But you can see the source code about *struct Table*.There are a array member and a Node*(list as hash part.)

Comment: Yes, it's a struct, not a union. Also, `pairs` iterates over the entire table, not just what internally is the "hash part". And, `ipairs` iterates over the positive integer keys from 1 and up to but not including the first `nil` value, which may or may not be the entirety of internally is the "array part."